# Include local html file in event (no server, no ajax)

Tags: javascript, html, request

The question boils down to this: how can I display a brand new `main` when someone press a button?

So a javascript code would look like this:

```
let post1 = document.getElementById('post1')
post1.onclick=function (){
  //bring in local file?
  //document.main.innerHTML=localHtmlFile
}
```

And the HTML

```
<body>
    <button id="post1">Post 1</button>
    <main> </main>
</body>
```

I know similar stuff is done with Ajax. But this is not a request to a server, but just to a file in the same computer.

Any idea?

---

## **Edit**

I'd just like some information for newbies like me:

> Note: For security reasons, you can't fetch() files from your local
> filesystem (or run other such operations locally); to run the above
> example locally you'll have to run the example through a local
> webserver. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Introducing#The_nature_of_asynchronous_code)

This probably applies to XMLHttpRequests too.

(So as dumb as it seems we cant fetch our own files.)

Comment: You can add a file upload input `<input type="file">` then when user browse to that file you can read using the FileReader object. But if you meant without uploader then it's not possible

Comment: no idea what you mean pal @Viney. Any other hint?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DiegoTc/y6gtD/

Answer (score 0):

I have added id to main tag, and stored a html string on localHtmlFile field.

try it

```js
window.localStorage.setItem('page', "<div>new content</div>");

   
let post1 = document.getElementById('post1')
post1.onclick=function (){
  //can I include something similar to this?
  document.getElementById('main').innerHTML=window.localStorage.readItem('page');
}
```

```html
<body>
    <button id="post1">Post 1</button>
    <main id="main">
    </main>
</body>
```

Comment: That's manually written. It's not what I mean. How do you get an html file inside javascript?I want localHtmlFile to be a file, if that makes sense.

Comment: javascript have a limited space to work, you can store a file on local store

Comment: thanks for theanswer. Even though it's not what i'm looking for, i learnt  quite a lot.